# Remove warnings of package dependency with R CMD check

Tags: r, meteor-packages

I build my `rpackage` with Rstudio, everything goes fine. When use `check` button in `rstudio`, it gives me some warnings, listed below:

```
* checking whether package 'rpackage' can be installed ... WARNING
Found the following significant warnings:
  Warning: package 'e1071' was built under R version 3.2.4
  Warning: package 'frbs' was built under R version 3.2.4
  Warning: package 'randomForest' was built under R version 3.2.4
  Warning: package 'R.matlab' was built under R version 3.2.4
  Warning: package 'PerformanceAnalytics' was built under R version 3.2.4
  Warning: package 'xts' was built under R version 3.2.4
  Warning: package 'zoo' was built under R version 3.2.4
```

How can I remove these warnings?

Additionally, here is part of my `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
Depends: e1071(>= 1.6-7),frbs(>= 3.1-0),randomForest(>= 4.6-12), R.matlab(>= 3.5.1), PerformanceAnalytics(>= 1.4.3541)
License: No License
LazyData: No
RoxygenNote: 5.0.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's likely your R version is out of date: the R version used (`3.2.4`) to build these packages is ahead of yours, and so a warning is returned.

You can check your current version either in the preamble when you launch a new session or by typing `R.version`.

Most of the time it has no practical consequences (for small gaps between R versions), but: i) the function you use may have been affected by version change and ii) it's a good idea to have the last R stable version.